# How to not close InfoWindow when MouseOver another Marker? Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem when I clicked a Marker on the map, InfoWindow opened but when I hover Hover mouse over another Marker, InfoWindow was clicked it was closed.
Now I have to make InfoWindow not closed when Hover mouse over another position, only when I click on Marker to close the old InfoWindow to open the new InfoWindow?

Like this http://aqicn.org/here/

**My Javascript**

```
markers.forEach(function(diadiem) {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: diadiem.position,
                    icon: icons[diadiem.type].icon,
                    map: map
                  });

                  // Click marker
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
                        return function() {
                          infowindow.setContent('Ok click');             
                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                      })(marker));

                  // Hover mouse
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker) {
                        return function() {
                          infowindow.setContent('OK hover');
                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                      })(marker));
});
```

Comment: You want the info window to close only when another marker is clicked on? i.e. one info window open at a time?

Comment: @JohnM Exactly! I want it like this http://aqicn.org/here/

Comment: That link is not what you ask in your question.  The markers don't have the same onClick event (onclick opens a kind of infoWindow, hover opens a smaller tooltip).  Also it's not Google Maps.  If my answer doesn't fit your request, please reformulate your question a little.

Answer (score 0):

Now you only have one infoWindow, that gets repositioned and gets a new content with each hover.
You can also make a new infowindow each time.
Like this.

Notice, this will generate doubles

```
// Hover mouse
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker) {
  return function() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setContent('OK hover');
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
})(marker));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem myself successfully!

By creating 2 different InfoWindow

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

markers.forEach(function(diadiem) {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: diadiem.position,
                    icon: icons[diadiem.type].icon,
                    map: map
                  });

                  // Click marker
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
                        return function() {
                          infowindow.setContent('Ok click');             
                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                          infowindow2.close(map, marker);
                        }
                      })(marker));

                  // Hover mouse
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker) {
                        return function() {
                          infowindow2.setContent('OK hover');
                          infowindow2.open(map, marker);
                        }
                      })(marker));
});
```